# True stringify of DateTime

Tags: json, perl, datetime, cpan

According to:

http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-1.43/lib/DateTime.pm#Formatters_And_Stringification

the following will work:

```
use DateTime;
$dt = DateTime->new( ... );
print $dt;  # as string
```

and it does.

However, when using the JSON module to embed the created $dt string as a json-encoded data structure as follows:

```
use JSON;
my $json = JSON::encode_json( { dt => $dt } );
```

The JSON module is throwing the following exception:

```
encountered object '2017-08-02', but neither allow_blessed nor convert_blessed settings are enabled at ...
```

I can work around the issue as follows:

```
my $json = JSON::encode_json( { dt => substr($dt,0) } );
```

but wonder if there's a cleaner way to get a "true" string out of DateTime?

I've looked through the DateTime docs but I don't see an explicit stringify() to create the true string as required by JSON.

EDIT: In the constructor, I specify a desired output format via 'formatter'. I'd like to get a string using the already-specified format, and not specify the format again (which would be against DRY principle...)

EDIT2: Interpolating the string is a good solution if just $dt, but doesn't work if $dt is actually a moose attribute (i.e. "$person->birth_d").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `"$dt"` or `"".$o->dt`. Like your solution, it's short for

```
$dt->formatter ? $dt->formatter->format_datetime($dt) : $dt->iso8601
```

If you want a specific format, there's `$dt->strftime`, `$dt->iso8601`, or you could use a [*DateTime::Format::*](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=DateTime%3A%3AFormat&mode=module) module.

Comment: ... Can't locate object method "stringify" via package "DateTime"

Comment: Yeah, I mis-remembered. The (undocumented, internal) method is actually named `_stringify`, but I wouldn't use that. Already fixed.

Comment: Alas, i was hoping for a true stringify somewhere, but I will accept this answer. I also added a stringify() as a suggestion to the module maintainer: https://github.com/houseabsolute/DateTime.pm/issues/58

Comment: What are you talking about? How you can get any true-er stringify than the `stringify` opcode? `perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'"$dt"'`

Comment: `"".$person->birth_d`

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly interpolate the object in a string (`"$dt"`) or call the method that's actually getting called (`$dt->iso8601`).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use DateTime;

my $dt = DateTime->now;

say $dt;
say "$dt";
say $dt->iso8601;
```

Output:

```
2017-08-02T19:54:22
2017-08-02T19:54:22
2017-08-02T19:54:22
```

Comment: Re "*or call the method that's actually getting called (`$dt->iso8601`)*", No, not quite. `"$dt"` is equivalent to `$dt->formatter ? $dt->formatter->format_datetime($dt) : $dt->iso8601`.